# How to bulk fetch by ids in couchdb without creating a view

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I need to fetch couchdb documents by a bunch of ids. Is there an request / API to do it ?
I don't want to create a view (id, docs) and then do a find by keys.
when the id b-tree already exists

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the bulk API documented [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-get).

It could look something like below.

- Pass in the keys as part of the body via a POST
- Pass in the name of the db (in the example below, it's `demodb`)
- in the url, use the `_all_docs` for the view
- if you want the entire documents returned (and not just the `rev`), be sure to pass `include_docs=true`

`curl -d '{"keys":["docId1","docId2","docId3"]}' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/demodb/_all_docs?include_docs=true`

Comment: API Link is dead.  Is there any limit to the number of IDs you can request?  I am looking at requesting 48,000+ documents for bulk processing on a server.

Comment: I haven't used CouchDB for 5 years. :) The docs are all here and this looks relevant. https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html?highlight=bulk%20fetch#db-bulk-get

Comment: You can also add the keys in a separate json file, e.g., `keys.json` and call the API:
`curl -d @keys.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/demodb/_all_docs?include_docs=true`

Comment: The solution is idiomatic but it does violate the constraint of the question of not using a view since _all_documets is a view

Comment: @RuneFS - They said: `"I don't want to create a view"` not that a built-in view wasn't OK. If there's a better way more than **10 years** after I answered this originally, please add it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch a range of documents, you can also use `startkey_docid` and `limit` parameters like you would in a view.

What you do is a GET request to a URL like

`http://127.0.0.1:5984/demodb/_all_docs?startkey_docid="docId1"&limit=5`

Once you have your set of results, you can use the last returned it as the next startkey and run the request again. This has the benefit of skipping view indexing processes (which can be a pain in the ass for large databases).

Answer (score 0):

Documented in the CouchDB API, [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-get).

If you're using the `python-couchdb` library, you can use:

`_, _, response = <your_db>.resource.post_json('_bulk_get', {'docs': [{'id': '<1st_doc_id>'}, {'id': '<2nd_doc_id>'}]})`

Your results will be in `response['results']`.